# Найти количество повторений числа оптимально

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Язык: с++

Вводится массив a с N<10^6 элементами в неубывающем порядке , а также массив b c M < 2*10^5 элементами. Нужно для каждого элемента b ввести сколько раз он повторяется в a. Ограничение во времени 1с. Для решения пытался просто придумать две функции binaryleft и binaryright которые считают номер правого и левого края данного числа (бинарным поиском), после чего количество элементов будет просто binaryright-binaryleft + 1. Код работает, но получается ограничение во времени. Где лучше улучшить или оптимизировать код? Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int binaryleft(int* a,int N, int t, int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin > end){ return -1; }  
    else {
        int middle = (begin + end) / 2;
        if (t < a[middle])
        {
            return binaryleft(a, N, t, begin, middle - 1);
        }
        else {
            if (t > a[middle])
            {
                return binaryleft(a, N, t, middle + 1, end);
            }
            else {
                if (t == a[middle] && (t != a[middle - 1] || middle == 0))
                {
                    return middle;
                }
                else { return binaryleft(a, N, t, begin, middle - 1); }
            }
        }
    }
}
int binaryright(int* a, int N, int t, int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin > end)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int middle = (begin + end) / 2;
        if (t < a[middle])
        {
            return binaryright(a, N, t, begin, middle - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            if (t > a[middle])
            {
                return binaryright(a, N, t, middle + 1, end);
            }
            else {
                if (t == a[middle] && (t != a[middle + 1] || middle == N - 1))
                {
                    return middle;
                }
                else { return binaryright(a, N, t, middle + 1, end); }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int* a = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int M;
    cin >> M;
    int* b = new int[M];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        cin >> b[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if (binaryright(a, N, b[i], 0, N - 1) >= 0) {
            cout << binaryright(a, N, b[i], 0, N - 1) - binaryleft(a, N, b[i], 0, N - 1) + 1 << endl;
        }
        else { cout << 0 << endl; }
    }

}
```

Примечание: я начинающий в программировании, так что я бы предпочел советы без наворочек из библиотек языка, т.е. объяснение на фунд. уровне.

Comment: Сортировка, сортировка, *однократный* проход по двум отсортированным массивам... Ваша попытка решения полагает, что массив из N чисел упорядочен - но что-то я не вижу этого в условии...

Comment: В условии я написал что "массив с N элементами в неубывающем порядке"

Comment: *В условии я написал что "массив с N элементами в неубывающем порядке"* В условии это сказано ТОЛЬКО про первый массив, и НЕ СКАЗАНО про второй. Так что второй тоже надо сортировать. Также не указано, возможно ли наличие в одном массиве значения, отсутствующего во втором - причём в оба направления.

Comment: То есть вместо того чтобы циклически перебирать ответ для каждого элементам второго массива, будет оптимальное его сначала упорядочить, а потом уже с ним по хитрому работать?

Comment: Да нет там ничего хитрого. Обычный параллельный проход. В среднем на один элемент второго массива будет 5 элементов в первом - так что лучше прямой скан (5 сравнений на элемент), чем бинарный поиск.

Comment: Ну наверное более оптимальный способ связан с деревьями.... дальше подумайте чуть-чуть что ж произойдет при добавлении одинаковых членов в дерево))